# Migrating from Carrierwave local to S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Our server ran into a file limit issue with carrierwave. Over 36000 files. We are now going to move to S3.

Is there a way to migrate the files over to S3? When we launched the code on production none of the images showed up and there was a `duh` moment. It's trying to grab the files from s3 when they are locally stored on the server still.

How do we migrate the files over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload the files to s3 via the s3 console in the s3 file manager. Or by using a plugin such as S3Fox for FireFox. You'll just need to make sure the pathing and the s3 bucket are such that Carrierwave will know how to point to the image via the right set of subfolders, etc.

Comment: How do I update all the columns in the db to point to the Amazon paths?

Comment: The columns in the db just mention the file name, right? It's not the columns in the db you need to worry about, it's the path that the uploader states. The uploader uses data from the model to generate the path based on a common pattern.